# How to install headers while no library is present (A header-only lib)?

Tags: c++, autotools, automake

I need to install some headers (`.hpp`) in standard include dir. How do I tell `automake` to install them while there is no object to be compiled? Normally I put this lines in my `Makefile.am`:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = \
    foo.cpp \
    bar.cpp
foo_includedir = $(includedir)/foo
foo_include_HEADERS = \
    foo.hpp \
    bar.hpp \
    ../config.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`_DATA`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Uniform) primary:

```
foodir = $(includedir)/foo
foo_DATA = foo.hpp bar.hpp ../config.h
```